# SQL order by month DESC and year ASC

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `billing` 
where source = 'VOIP' 
group by month(timestamp), year(timestamp) 
order by month(timestamp) desc, year(timestamp) asc
```

the above query is returning this order:

```
2014-12-01
2014-11-01
2014-10-01
2015-05-01
2015-04-01
2015-03-01
2015-02-01
2015-01-01
```

i want to order like so:

```
2015-05-01
2015-04-01
2015-03-01
2015-02-01
2015-01-01
2014-12-01
2014-11-01
2014-10-01
```

Comment: The results you show are exactly what you indicate you want (month descending and year ascending). What is the actual result you're trying to obtain?

Answer (score 2):

How about just ordering by the date in descending order?

```
SELECT *
FROM `billing` 
where source = 'VOIP' 
group by month(timestamp), year(timestamp) 
order by MIN(timestamp) desc;
```

Note:  You should *never* use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  You should explicitly select the columns you want, along with the aggregation functions.  Something like:

```
SELECT month(timestamp), year(timestamp), count(*)
FROM `billing` 
where source = 'VOIP' 
group by month(timestamp), year(timestamp) 
order by MIN(timestamp) desc;
```

(This gets the number of records for each month.)